# Why do we initialize the size of an array, if it is possible to add elements more than the size?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, multidimensional-array, initialization

I quietly new to programming. So I read somewhere that we should initialize the array with the size,otherwise compilation error will be thrown. So In the below code i have initialized the array with size 3, that means only 3 elements can be stored in the array, right? starting from 0 to 2. but when I run the code and by mistake i have given 4 digits separated by space, as inputs. I expected an index out of bound exception, but to my surprise there were no errors and when I tried to print the digits of array into the console, all the 4 digits got printed. How is is even possible?

```
int[] arr = new int[3];
            arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

I even want to know if there is a same way to read a Multi dimensional array with LINQ as above.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: `ToArray` create a new array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have allocated another separate chunk of memory, the original array of 3 goes out of scope

[Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netcore-3.1)

> Creates an array from a `IEnumerable<T>`.

It's the same as doing this.

```
var arr = new int[3]; // allocate
arr = new int[4]; // allocate again to same variable, which points to new memory
```

The original allocation goes out of scope

It's just the way references work in .net, when you create an array, you allocate a portion of memory somewhere and your variable references that portion of memory. When you assign a new instance to that variable, you create a new portion of memory somewhere else, and your variable takes that reference to the new memory.

Comment: Ok @TheGeneral.Thanks much!!! But do we have a similar way or approach to read a multi dimensional array?

Comment: @Saranya you will need to be more specific, its unclear what you are asking

Comment: If i understand what you are asking, you can do it with any variable, reference or value type, its just the way .net works

Answer (score 0):

because `ToArray` method copies the elements from the list to a new array.

Comment: Ok Vivek.Thanks much!!! But do we have a similar way or approach to read a multi dimensional array?